# Why proc/meminfo Active+inactive (file) != cached?

Tags: linux, memory, memcached

[image]

Cached: Memory in the pagecach

Active(file): Pagecache memory that has been used more recently and usually not reclaimed until needed

Inactive(file): Pagecache memory that can be reclaimed without huge performance impact

I expected it to be Active+Inactive (file) = cached ?